# Character Remaining for p:editor Primefaces

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am aware that Primefaces provides functionality for character remaining for p:inputTextarea as shown in the code below

```
<p:inputTextarea rows="1" cols="85" counter="counter" maxlength="100" counterTemplate="{0} characters remaining" value="#{managedBean.inputvalue}" ></p:inputTextarea>
<h:outputText />
<h:outputText id="counter" />
```

But I want to do the same thing in p:editor. How to do that? Is primefaces provides such functionality or do I have to achieve this by other means {like coding this functinality}.

TIA

Comment: Just FYI `p:editor` is now deprecated in favour of `p:textEditor`, which does not seem to offer `maxlength` at all. And with Primefaces: 6.1.RC2 (community edition), `p:editor` issues a warning that `Maxlength option is deprecated and will be removed in a future version`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<p:editor` has no option for that, you can use jquery to solve that. My solution is bind keyup event to your editor
I have just tested, my example have one form(id: fm), one editor(id:rongnk),one outputtext(id:txt):

```
<h:body onload="bindiframe()">
        <h:form id="fm"> 
            <p:editor id="rongnk" value="xxx">
            </p:editor>
            <h:outputText id="txt"/>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var imax = 50;
                function bindiframe(){
                    $('#fm\\:rongnk').find('iframe').contents().find("body").on('keyup', function(e) {
                        ilength = $('#fm\\:rongnk').find('iframe').contents().find("body").text().length;
                        $('#fm\\:txt').html('Remain:' + (imax - ilength));
                    });
                }
            </script>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
```

Answer (score 3):

As far as I can judge from documentation of [`<p:editor>` tag](http://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/3.5/primefaces-p/editor.html) there is no attribute with a 'counter' functionality. Still, there is `maxlength` attribute.

So, your best bet is to attach a JavaScript function to handle `change` event by specifying `onchange="checkTextLength(this)"`. To write the function, you need to calculate the difference between max text length and current text length with PrimeFaces' editor client side API and basing on the result update a placeholder.

Comment: I can not see `maxlength` attribute ?

Comment: @RongNK Look better: the last one.

Comment: Done the same to yours :) But still I'm sure that client side API should have the functions to evaluate maxsize and text length, so you'd better check for it in Firebug, as I don't have access to it at the moment. I guess that your solution is too dependent on setup of editor. Also, I'd remove repetitive code from the binding and would definitely put `#{bean.maxSize}` instead of your `50`.

Comment: Yes, i code that, and the person, who ask, have to done his job :)

Comment: Just FYI `p:editor` is now deprecated in favour of `p:textEditor`, which does not seem to offer `maxlength` at all. And with Primefaces: 6.1.RC2 (community edition), `p:editor` issues a warning that `Maxlength option is deprecated and will be removed in a future version`.